# Unable to find assembly 'NHibernate when publishing WPF/xbap

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, publish, xbap

Trying to publish a WPF project as an xbap to an IIS instance, while internally using NHibernate + SQL CE for storage.

Getting

Startup URI: http://***/PROJ/WpfBrowserTest.xbap
Application Identity: http://***/PROJ/WpfBrowserTest.xbap#WpfBrowserTest.xbap, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df2c8f8ef56d960e, processorArchitecture=msil/WpfBrowserTest.exe, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df2c8f8ef56d960e, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'NHibernate, Version=1.2.0.3001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()

For other dependencies (3rd party libs) we have signed/strong named some other (Interop) assemblies, involving disassembling, signing, reassembling them.

Didn't find much of value on Google/StackOverflow. Any ideas on what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this blog,

http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/09/12/setting-the-publish-status-to-include-for-3rd-party-files-with-xbap-deployments.aspx

I started looking for subdependencies on NHibernate.dll- while I didn't have an hibernate.cfg.xml - it's done programmatically - I realized I'd missed including System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll in the References.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Bill!

R/j